# Convergence in $L^p([0,1])$ of $f_n(x) = n\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**My attempt**

**1)**  For $1 \leq p < 2$ we have:

$$ \|f_n\|_p ^p =
\int_{0}^{1}{|f_n(x)|^p}dx = 
\int_{0}^{1}{n^p\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})}}dx = \frac{n^{p-1}}{n+1} 
\to 0$$

Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^p([0,1])$ if $1 \leq p < 2$

**2)**  For $ p > 2$ we have:

$$ \|f_n\|_p ^p =
\int_{0}^{1}{|f_n(x)|^p}dx = 
\int_{0}^{1}{n^p\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})}}dx = \frac{n^{p-1}}{n+1} 
\to \infty$$

Then $f_n \to \infty$ in $L^p([0,1])$ if $p > 2$

I'm not sure about this last step. ($\|f_n\| \to \infty   \Rightarrow  f_n \to \infty$)

And I'm having trouble with $p = 2 $.
$$ \|f_n\|_2 ^2=
\int_{0}^{1}{|f_n(x)|^2}dx = 
\int_{0}^{1}{n^2\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})}}dx = \frac{n}{n+1} 
\to 1$$

Can anyone help me finish the exercise?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere, so if the limit exists in $L^p$ for $p<\infty$, it must also be zero. Thus, for convergence in $L^p$, you need $||f_n||_p \to 0$.

Note that $||f_n||_p^p = \int_0^1 n^p \chi_{(1/(n+1),1/n)} dx = n^p (1/n - 1/(n+1))$.

Thus, if $||f_n||_p^p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, you have convergence in that $L^p$ norm. If not, you don't.

What about the $\infty$-norm? Well, $||f_n||_\infty = n$. So, you also don't converge in this norm.